# Include certain escapement symbols into ANTLR Lexer rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a parser in Antlr4 and Python. Below is the Lexer rules I created in Antlr.

```
VARIABLE_ID :   [$][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
ARRAY_ID    :   [*][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
STRINGCONST :   ["][/|:.a-zA-Z0-9 ]+["];
WS          :   [ \r\t\f\n]+ -> skip;
```

I am looking at the `STRINGCONST` rule and I'm trying to add symbols such as `-` and `~`, however, since they are escapement characters, Antlr is just throwing errors for me. I've tried escaping them with themselves and I haven't been able to get that to work.

Is there a way to include them in the `STRINGCONST` rule? The basic idea is that I want a string to be identified as any character between two `" "` marks however I'm happy to limit it to what's currently in the rule as long as I can get `-` and `~` in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape chars by adding a `\` in front of them:

```
STRINGCONST :   ["] [/|:.a-zA-Z0-9 \-~]+ ["];
```

And note that `~`  has no  special meaning inside a char class (only outside of them), so `~` doesn't need to be escaped.